# how to - Cross site publishing in SharePoint Online

Tags: office-365, cross-site-publishing

I want to use cross site publishing in SharePoint online. Can you one suggest me some tutorial for implementing this. I am getting lot many tutorials for this but not for online. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

here are the steps:

1. [Activate the Cross-Site Publishing feature in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Activate-the-Cross-Site-Publishing-feature-in-SharePoint-aef0b911-40d7-4d01-a97a-aae8c77dc177?CTT=1&CorrelationId=48a2c8fb-b3bd-4017-8ef4-e833fa7bfb5a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
2. Now go to DL/list which you want use as a catalog.[Enable a library or list as a catalog in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Enable-a-library-or-list-as-a-catalog-in-SharePoint-d1d377f3-77d5-4023-82d6-0a04e8c74ba4?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE)
3. Do a full crawl of the content source that contains the catalog. See
   [Manually request crawling and re-indexing](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518).
4. Enable the SharePoint Server Publishing feature on the publishing
   site. See [Enable publishing features](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518).
5. [Enable managed navigation](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Enable-managed-navigation-49a067dc-77d2-455d-9e77-250ec7cc0a6d) on the publishing site.
6. Make the tagging term set that is used by the catalog [available to
   the publishing site collection.](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/available-to-the-publishing-site-collection-5e1271e2-6e1f-4d22-8a0d-b2648a412ca7)
7. Make sure that you’re a member of the Owners SharePoint group on the
   publishing site.
8. [Connect a publishing site to a catalog in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Connect-and-disconnect-a-publishing-site-to-a-catalog-in-SharePoint-df2bdea4-ceb0-459a-91d2-a47a1d807d71?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE)
9. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj656774(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I am getting below error while connecting:The shared catalog tagging field "" could not be found. You must select the tagging field for this catalog. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online/Office 365 doesn’t currently support "Cross Site Publishing" features.Below link will outline several alternatives for delivering cross-site and search-driven content in SharePoint Online and how to template these views for reuse.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2013/04/01/cross-site-publishing-alternatives-in-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365/

Comment: Please do not just copy paste large amounts of text from a blog post without making it clear that you are quoting it

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment on the only upvoted "Answer" I had to add my own and second the previous answer by Niranjan. Microsoft says themselves that Cross Site Publishing is not available in Sharepoint Online, which the OP explicitly states.

> This capability is not available in SharePoint Online. Cross-site publishing capability is only available in on-premises deployments.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/cross-site-publishing-in-sharepoint